# How to calculate the real video frame rate both in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: html5-video, webrtc

How to properly calculate the current frame rate of the video element?

Or is there even a built-in function I can get from it?

On chrome side, I can calculate using below function

```
function calcFrameRate(){
  window.currentFrameRate = 0;
  window.currentFrameCount = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
    window.currentFrameRate = (video.webkitDecodedFrameCount - window.currentFrameCount) / 10.0;
    window.currentFrameCount = video.webkitDecodedFrameCount;
  }, 10000);
}
```

However `webkitDecodedFrameCount` does not implemented in Safari, any idea how to accomplish in Safari?

Comment: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/

Comment: Thank you @G-Man But it only shows the input parameters, it does not show the exact frameRate which is using.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: It seems only chrome, so I only implement on chrome at that time @Luz

Comment: On Firefox you can make use of `video.mozPaintedFrames`. [Video Metrics](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics)